# Java XMLStreamWriter serialises '£' as different byte data when inside a maven build unit test (on Windows)

Tags: java, xml, windows, utf-8, character-encoding

The following unit test uses the Java XML API to generate a simple XML document.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.stream.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class XmlErrorTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws XMLStreamException {

        final XMLOutputFactory xmlOutFact = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();    
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final XMLStreamWriter xwtr = xmlOutFact.createXMLStreamWriter(baos);

        xwtr.writeStartDocument();
        xwtr.writeStartElement("Test");
        xwtr.writeCharacters(Character.toString('£'));
        xwtr.writeEndElement();
        xwtr.writeEndDocument();

        xwtr.close();

        System.out.println(baos.toString());
        final byte[] bs = baos.toByteArray();
        for (int i = 27; i < 31; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i + " : " + bs[i] + "(" + (char)bs[i] + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the test directly with an IDE (Intellij) then it outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Test>£</Test>
27 : 62(>)
28 : -62(ￂ)
29 : -93(ﾣ)
30 : 60(<)
```

I.e. the £ symbol is reproduced correctly in the output. If I run the test within a Maven build then I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Test>�</Test>
27 : 62(>)
28 : -93(?)
29 : 60(<)
30 : 47(/)
```

I.e. the generated byte data appears to be incorrect - it looks like it dropped a byte.

Note, I am specifying the following in a parent pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

Why does is the XML £ symbol "corrupted" when I run the test from Maven? This only happens on Windows - Linux and MacOS builds seem unafflicted.

This is with Java 1.8.0_131 and Maven 3.3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try wrapping the OutputStream with a Writer with specified encoding:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final OutputStreamWriter stringWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final XMLStreamWriter xwtr = xmlOutFact.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
```

The reason is the default charset of JVM, when you run with IntelliJ, it runs with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 param added.

You can check the current encoding used by using this:

```
Charset defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();
System.out.println(defaultCharset);
```

You can add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 into maven when running, but IMHO,we should not depend on the default encoding, always specify the encoding when you work with byte/string conversion. Ex:
Instead of:

```
//using default charset, we cannot know in runtime    
"test".getBytes();
String foo = new String(bytes);
Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

Just use this:

```
"test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String foo = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

The maven surefire plugin uses the encoding of your system.

So you have to encode it the same way:

```
    final XMLOutputFactory xmlOutFact = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();    
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final XMLStreamWriter xwtr = xmlOutFact.createXMLStreamWriter(baos, "ISO-8859-1");

    xwtr.writeStartDocument("ISO-8859-1", "1.0");
```

Or you preferable configure the surefire plugin to use UTF-8:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```